# k-means algorithm in Matlab giving wrong answer?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following doubt:
I am using the k-means function of Matlab, and I just want to use the vanilla Lloyd's algorithm, with my desired set of initialization points. I use the following code, where 'start' is my initialization vector.

```
kmeans(data,[],'Start',start, 'OnlinePhase', 'off');
```

Suppose my data is 2-D in the range (-2,-1)X(2,1), and I initialize my starting points at (-10,0) and (0,0). Ideally, I should get all the points in one cluster, and none in other, but I am getting two clusters in the answer (as (-10,0) is really far away, so it should converge in one iteration). How is that possible? I read the description of the k-means algorithm in the Matlab site, and it seems that this shouldn't be the answer.

[image: k-means, original data and clustered data]

Comment: What is the mean of 0 points? That is where the one centroid is shifted to after the first iteration... It seems logical to build in a test to make sure the initialization is correct, and ignore it if it is not.

Comment: "It seems logical to build in a test to make sure the initialization is correct", build a test as in?

Comment: A test as in: the mean for one given centroid is 0/0=NaN, can’t compute with that, let’s use our default initialization instead.

Comment: @CrisLuego it can be okay to have empty clusters remain where they were. Maybe you are clustering with previous knowledge about the centers, and one of your initial classes does not occur in the new sample. Then that class should remain empty, and the cluster maybe should not move.

Comment: I think @CrisLuengo might be right, that if there is some terrible initialization, then Matlab's kmeans algo probably chooses a default initialization.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse the graph shows the result with that bad initialization. Logic says that everything should be in one cluster, but they take care of the bad case, by doing a default initialization, as the graph shows.

Comment: @the_dude your plot wasn't clear enough then (or just too tiny) - I may have misread it as the marker on the far left being the resulting center. But yes. The handling of empty clusters is even configurable. The default is to use the farthest data point as new cluster center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No point is closest to the badly chosen center.** So *cannot* be recomputed, and will be replaced with a new center (see the documentation). All points are first assigned to the 0,0 cluster. Some algorithms will even fail badly with a division by 0, or discard this center and reduce to k=1. In Matlab, you can choose the handling - by default it will choose the point farthest from all centers as replacement.

Keeping an empty cluster center where it is is fairly reasonable, IMHO, as it won't change any cluster enumeration you had in mind when choosing the initial centers, and (when the initial centers are well chosen) it may even become non-empty again eventually, when the other centers continue to move (not here though).

Comment: Yes, and the way to achieve empty cluster is Matlab is  
    `kmeans(data,[],'Start',start, 'OnlinePhase', 'off','EmptyAction','drop');`